# How do I detect submitted button with ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a form on my front-end and when the submit button is `clicked` I want to send the details to my `get-emp.php` file `without page reload`.

The code looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<form class="form-emp-details hide" action="">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-emp-firstname" name="input_emp_firstname">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-emp-lastname" name="input_emp_lastname">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit-1" name="submit_emp_details">Save</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**custom.js**

```
  $(".form-emp-details").("submit", function(e) {

    var input_first_name = $(".input-emp-firstname").val();


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get-emp.php",
      data: {
        input_emp_firstname:input_first_name,     
      },
      success: function(data) {         
        console.log(data)   
      },
      error: function(xhr,status,error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });


  });
```

**get-emp.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_emp_details'])) {
  $firstname = $_POST['input_emp_firstname'];
  echo $firstname;
}
```

I want to display the submitted form data on `get-emp.php` file **but** it seems that I am not able to detect the submitted button and echo the form data on.

My goal is to capture all form data with a single request variable or identifier `$_POST['submit_emp_details']`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you didn't pass `submit_emp_details` to get it with `$_POST['submit_emp_details'])` so your code always returns empty .. use `if(isset($_POST['input_emp_firstname']))`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef My goal is to get all form data with just a single identifier `$_POST['identifier']`. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: look @Canon you can use  `data: $(this).serialize(),` ChiKa says on his answer .. and on php you need to loop through the posted data `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#MyformId").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
              // success..
           }
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You passing the POST data of firstname and lastname by:

> input_emp_firstname
>
> input_emp_lastname

---

so, you need to change the `$_POST['submit_emp_details']` to `$_POST['input_emp_firstname']` on file get-emp.php to

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input_emp_firstname'])) {
  $firstname = $_POST['input_emp_firstname'];
  echo $firstname;
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get-emp.php",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    submit_emp_details: {
            input_emp_firstname:input_first_name, 
            input_emp_lastname:input_last_name
    }
  },
  success: function(data) {

    console.log(data)

  },
  error: function(xhr,status,error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Do you have any idea how to capture all form data with just `$_POST['submit_emp_details']` ?

Comment: hi @ConanCarroll please check the Edit 2